# Let A be a denumerable set. Prove that the set $\{B:B\subset A\}$ and cardinality of B=1 of all 1-element subsets of A is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So my original idea was to show that the countable union of countable sets is countable since I know that each set has one element. I'm not exactly sure how to start this off though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think iit is cleanest to use an explicit bijection between $A$ and the set of all one-element subsets of $A$. You already know that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Comment: I would use the definition of countable (injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$) and then you use the existence of a bijection from each element of $A$ to the $1$-element set containing this particular element.

Comment: So, I'm used to doing my functions as N to whatever. So since A has n elements in it, could I do a bijection from N to $\{a_{1}...a_{n}\}$?

Comment: Because $x\mapsto \{x\}$ is a bijection from $A$ to the set of singleton subsets of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that denumerable doesn't means finite, denumerable means that there exist an injective map from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Take $f$ this injective map, and let:

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\phi & : & B & \to & A \\
 & & \{x\} & \mapsto & x \\
\end{array}$

$\phi$ is clearly  injective (and furthermore bijective), then $f \circ \phi$ is  injective from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

We conclude from there that $B$ is denumerable.